# Why do Microsoft Office Excel and Word not know how to open files?

Tags: microsoft-excel, windows-vista, microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I have Windows Vista and Office 2007.

Whenever I click on a document such as an Excel or Word document I get this error.

[image: error]

It's annoying as I have to wait for the application to load, get the error and then re-open the file.

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Answer (score 3):

This may be a known bug as Microsoft has a Knowledgebase article about it:
["Cannot find the file" error message when you try to open a workbook by double-clicking the .xls file](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323216)

> 1. Click Start, and then click Run.
> 2. In the Open box, type `regedit`, and then click OK.
> 3. In Registry Editor, locate the following subkey in the registry:
>       `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office`
> 4. Expand the subkey that corresponds to the earlier version of Excel, and then click the `Excel` subkey.
> 5. Right-click the `Excel` subkey, and then click `Rename`.
> 6. Type `OldExcel`, and then press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.
> 7. Repeat steps 4 through 6 for any other subkeys for earlier versions of Excel.
> 8. Locate the following subkey:
>      `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Office`
> 9. Expand the subkey that corresponds to the earlier version of Excel, and then click the `Excel` subkey.
> 10. Right-click the `Excel` subkey, and then click Rename.
> 11. Type `OldExcel`, and then press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.
> 12. Repeat steps 9 through 11 for any other subkeys for earlier versions of Excel.
> 13. Quit Registry Editor.
> 14. Start Excel. (This makes sure that the appropriate registry entries are created.)
> 15. Quit Excel.
> 16. Double-click an .xls file to start Excel and open the workbook.

Comment: This isn't a bug.  This is a configuration problem with the user's system.  There is a fix to this configuration problem.